# Error using native smiles of Android in text field (Unity3d)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I make application with `Unity3d` and build it for `Android`, when I write in input field android native smiles - I got error in line

```
(invalid utf-16 sequence at 1411555520 (missing surrogate tail)):
r.font.RequestCharactersInTexture(chars, size, style);
```

chars contains `string` than contains native android smiles. How I may support native smiles? I use own class for Input Field.

Comment: Emoji Assist : https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/53240  ( renders the native emoji / emojicons from android in a textfield using a input field )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, supporting emojis with Unity is hard. When I implemented this feature, it took about a month to finish it, with a custom text layout engine and string class. So, if this requirement is not particularly important, I would suggest axing this feature.

The reason behind this particular error is that Unity gets characters from the input string one by one, and updates the visual string every character. From the layman point of view, this makes complete sense. However, it doesn't take into account how UTF-16 encoding, which is used in C#, works.

UTF-16 encoding uses 16 bits per a single unicode characters. It is enough for almost all characters that you would normally use. (And, as every developer knows, "almost all" is a red flag that will lay dormant for a long time and then will explode and destroy everything you love.) But it so happens, that Emoji characters are do **not** fit into 16 bit UTF-16 character, and use a special case — **[surrogate pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF)**:

[image: A table with different characters in UTF8 and UTF16 representation]

Surrogate pair is a **pair** of UTF-16 characters that represent a single Unicode character. That means that they don't have any meaning on their own individually, and when you try to render a UTF-16 character that is a surrogate head or surrogate tail, you can expect to get an error like this, or something similar.

Essentially, what you need to implement is some kind of buffer, that will accept C# UTF-16 characters one by one, and then pass them to rendering code when it verifies that all surrogate pairs are closed.

Oh, and I almost forgot! Some Emoji characters, like country flags, are represented by **two unicode characters**. Which means that they can potentially take up to **four UTF-16 characters**. Aren't text encodings fun?

Comment: I don't understand what you tried to say with this comment.

Comment: Let's I have string with smile. How I check that this string contains smile?

Comment: You can use unicode character tables, such as this http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: Then, I mush write many codes of smiles in my code (this is bad)(((

Comment: Yes. Of course, it would make more sense to move data outside of the code, but that's basically what I had to do: import this exact table to application. Also, you would have to re-write the font rendering if you want to display them on the screen.

Comment: Or maybe use native intput field in Android and IOS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77596/discussion-between-utyasheva-irina-and-max-yankov).